# Adding a success to AJAX JSON $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am new to JSON and I am trying to add a success callback on my JQuery AJAX post. The success will simply do a `location.reload()`.

Right now my `post` works fine in terms of updating my DB, but the reload sits outside of my AJAX method and it happens a split second before the controller can actually process the data meaning the automatically called reload occurs before the data is ready. I would like the reload to wait until the AJAX has finished its job.

**POST**

```
$.post(
      '/Users/customCreate',
      {
           'name': name,
           'birthday': birthday,
           'bio': bio
      },
            function (data) { },
            "json"
       );
       location.reload(); //Want this in the success function
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult customCreate(string name, string birthday, string bio)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if (name == null || birthday == null || bio == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        try
        {
            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(birthday);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                User user = new User();

                user.name = name;
                user.birthday = dt;
                user.bio = bio;  

                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have only used JSON/AJAX a tiny bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to include [the `forcedReload` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload) in your call to `.reload()` to ensure you don't just get the browser's cached version of the page from before the database update:

```
$.post('/Users/customCreate', {
    'name': name,
    'birthday': birthday,
    'bio': bio
}).done(function afterUserCreate(data) {
    location.reload(true);
});
```

(I also prefer to chain the `.done()` method after the `$.post()`, and naming all my functions, for added readability and troubleshooting.)

Comment: Ah yes! This `.done` thing is exactly what I need! The basic function with reload still happens before the data finishes processing, so thank you very much for having a solution that waits :) ! Quick question though, when I do a `.post`, how does it know when it is done? Does the controller tell it or what exactly occurs?

Comment: The web server issues a response. Depending on the headers in that response, jQuery will process `.done()` or `.fail()`. You can also use  `.always()`, which (as the name implies) will always be executed regardless of the web server's response.

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple:)

```
$.post(
      '/Users/customCreate',
      {
           'name': name,
           'birthday': birthday,
           'bio': bio
      },
            function (data) {location.reload();} //Now it's in the success function
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your post processing code in the Callback function

```
$.post(
      '/Users/customCreate',
      {
           'name': name,
           'birthday': birthday,
           'bio': bio
      },
            function (data) { location.reload();}

       );
```

Alternatively you can use the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function which accomplishes the same thing. It is more verbose and readable.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Users/customCreate',
    data: {
        'name': name,
        'birthday': birthday,
        'bio': bio
    },
    success: function (data) {
        location.reload();
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the reload in the success callback like this:

```
$.post(
      '/Users/customCreate',
      {
           'name': name,
           'birthday': birthday,
           'bio': bio
      },
            function (data) { location.reload(); }
      });
```